# bxSlider Delayed Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

My bxSlider horizontally spans 100% of the browser width - multiple (image) slides display across the viewport, with "moveSlides: 1" set in the options.

A total of 8 slides are being rotated. As I click the "next" arrow to progress through them, something odd is happening at the end. As the 8th slide initially enters the viewport from the right and I continue clicking, there aren't any images displaying to the right of it UNTIL it's about cycle out again through the left side, at which point slides #1-3 suddenly appear where they should in the sequence. From there, the cycle repeats, with the same scenario occurring once slide #8 enters the viewport again.

Basically, I want slide #1 and so forth to appear to the right of slide 8 as soon as they're supposed to show up in the viewport, without this lag. After inspecting the CSS, I'm pretty sure it's a matter of the viewport calculation being off (specifically, the "left" position of .bx-viewport).

How can this specific calculation (the wrapping of the slide lineup) in jquery.bxslider.js be modified? Or is there another approach I should take, one that wouldn't require tweaking the viewport calculations?

I have included the code and replicated the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/astewes/S7L2n/1/

I am using bxSlider with the following options:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('ul#homepage.bxslider').bxSlider({
    controls: true,
    displaySlideQty: 5,
    pager: false,
    startingSlide: 0,
    moveSlideQty: 1,
    infiniteLoop: true,
    preloadImages: 'all',
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    captions: false
  });
});
```

**EDIT**: I've updated the list of the options I'm using. I've been able to reduce the above-mentioned delay, but the slider still behaves strangely when cycling back around to image #1. `displaySlideQty` has proven useful in reducing the lag time, although I'm not sold on the idea of relying solely on it. Space between slides is also off (for portrait-sized images), but this is likely because I'm using a combination of portrait and landscape. I've tried dynamically changing widths of the portrait images, but the use of `display: table` and `display: table-cell` (to center everything) made that approach useless.

Comment: Without code, it's impossible to help. With a [Fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/) instead, it would be easy.

Comment: @AndreaLigios a fiddle should never be used instead of providing code, rather it should be in addition (in fact if you try and post a question with just a fiddle I believe the system stops you).

Comment: Obviously ;) Maybe I wasn't clear enough: code is the minimum, an extra fiddle is the best.